# How to model and measure cross-level interaction among multiple levels of data

Tags: regression, interaction, multilevel-analysis, marketing

I have a weekly data at Brand Level, Sub Segment level and Segment level (the other two are derived from rolling up the Brand level data).  The data includes product characteristics, sales, marketing and external factors like weather.

I want to model with "Market Share" as my dependent variable, and I've been asked to come up with an approach by which it is possible to:

- Identify key drivers(attributes) for the Market share for various "Brands" and "Sub Segments"
- Measure the effect of change in a brand level attribute on

  - Market share of the Brand
  - Market share of the sub segment in which brand is contained
  - Market share of the segment to which the brand belongs

For identifying key drivers I used feature selection techniques and logistic regression. But I'm not able to figure out a way to calculate these intra and inter level elasticities of "brand attributes".

I read about "Hierarchical linear models" but I'm not sure it will work in my case because the attributes at higher levels are just rolled up values of attributes at lower level.

Comment: What do you mean by "rolled up"?

Comment: Aggregated over the rows, example the prices of the brands are averaged to get the price of the subsegment after rolling up.